# Using previously downloaded debian packages for upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 13.04, debian, offline

Before upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 I downloaded most of required .deb packages separately. Now I have a folder with a lot of .deb packages needed for upgrade.

How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 using terminal in a way that the upgrade process uses my downloaded packages and will not re-download them separately? (However it may need to download the packages that I have not downloaded.)

Comment: Have you tried to place them on `/var/cache/apt/archives`? It is where apt stores the downloade files.

Comment: @Salem: Can I be sure that placing them in /var/cache/apt/archives will prevent re-downloading? Is there any command for adding packages and then upgrading?

Comment: See my answer. If you want to make sure apt works this way just download a small package deb (like [sl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/sl)), place it there and do a `sudo apt-get install sl`. You should see something like `Need to get 0 B/??? kB of archives.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the downloaded .deb's on `/var/cache/apt/archives` apt should use them instead of downloading all over again.

```
$ sudo cp /path/to/debs/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Please note that by itself this does not prevent the download of some packages. If there is some missing dependency or there is a newer version of a cached .deb apt should download them.

If you want to make sure that no downloads are made use `--no-download`:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade --no-download
```

#### Edit

If you are going to update using `do-release-upgrade` you cannot use `--no-download`, but it uses the same path to store packages.